# Is there any significant difference between "Flugzeug" and "Maschine"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

Until now, the only word I knew for airplane was "das Flugzeug", but today I saw this example in Duden:

> Seine Maschine fliegt noch in der Nacht Richtung Berlin ab.

I was surprised at the use of the word "die Maschine" and found out it can also mean "plane".

So, what is the difference between these two words and their usages?

Comment: Man sagt "meine Maschine" nur dann, wenn der Kontext (Flugreise) vollkommen klar ist. In allen anderen Fällen sagt man "Flugzeug" oder - flappsig - "Flieger" (letzteres nur im Mündlichen).

Comment: It's the same as the English speaking world says "machine" for computer. Germans use machine for plane but not for computers.

Comment: äüö   I am using *Maschine* for computer though (in German). It simply depends on context. When context is clear, you use *Maschine*. If you are a cook, you use your *Maschine* for mixing food. If you are a seamstress, you use your *Maschine* for sewing. If you are a pilot, you use your *Maschine* for flying. If you are a farmer, you use your *Maschine* for harvesting corn or whatever. If you have a dairy farm, you use your *Maschine* for milking. I use my *Maschine* for writing. A computer is anyway mostly just a modern *Schreibmaschine*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Maschine* is a [hyperonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy) of *Flugzeug*: the latter is a kind of machine, but there are many other kinds of machines.

> Seine Maschine flog nach Berlin.

In a sentence like this, the context makes it pretty clear that *Maschine* refers to an airplane. This figure of speech is called [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche). There are different types of synecdoche.

> - Er ging nach **Amerika**. (=die Vereinigten Staaten)
>     *totum pro parte* (the whole for the part)
> - Das kostet fünf Euro pro **Kopf**. (=Person)
>     *pars pro toto* (the part for the whole)
> - Hast du ein **Tempo**? (=Taschentuch)
>     *species pro genere* (the species for the genus)
> - Wir **Zweibeiner** glauben, daß wir die mächtigsten Wesen dieser Erde sind. (=Menschen)
>     *genus pro specie* (the genus for the species)

*Maschine* for *Flugzeug* is of the last type; the genus is used for the species.

These figures of speech can become lexicalised, i.e. conventional. In fact, [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maschine) has *Flugzeug* as meaning 2a) of *Maschine*. The same holds for all the other examples I gave: *Person* is listed in dictionaries as one meaning of *Kopf* etc.

Comment: Not sure whether English examples are the best choice to illustrate how something works in German. But even so, I do not understand the example "We mortals." Do you mean it refers just to humans rather than all mortal beings?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper While I believe that *synecdoche* works the same across languages, I replaced the English examples by German ones, as it seems more appropriate for the site. (And you understood the example involving *mortals* correctly.)

Comment: In der Lyrik kann man auch mit einem Motorrad nach Berlin fliegen, aber lass uns lieber nach Las Vegas reiten, die Sonne putzen.

Answer (score 5):

*Maschine* is a broader term, you often hear it instead of *Motorrad* (motorcycle) for example. This behavior is called [*Totum pro parte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totum_pro_parte), “the whole for a part“.

Comment: Calling this a *totum pro parte* seems a bit wide-stretched for me. It works only if you go beyond the apparatus itself and see *all types of machines* as a totum, and the sub-type of flying machines (airplanes) as *pars* of this *totum*. Is this an accepted use of *totum pro parte*? Similarly you may say *Er bestieg sein Tier* where actually a horse (*Pferd*) is meant. Still *totum pro parte*?

Comment: PS    I would rather say, a good *totum pro parte* is: *Der Kürschner nähte aus der Kuh eine Tasche* where actually not the entire *Kuh* is used for the bag but of course only the cow's hide, but for brevity in the furriers' trade they call that hide a cow.

Comment: It might be a bit streched, but from what I learned in German class this definitely still is a totum pro parte. If you call something by a (more) generic term it almost always falls under the definition of *totum pro parte*

Comment: Okay, perhaps I simply struggled a bit with going beyond one object (the cow --> its hide) and apply the concept on multiple things (all apparatuses --> only those that fly)

Comment: The contexts in which "Maschine" is used in the described ways are quite different IMHO. "Maschine" in the sense of "Motorrad" seems almost like biker jargon to me, and I rarely encounter it (which is possibly also related to the fact that I'm not in touch with many motorbike enthusiasts). "Motorrad" is the more "formal" term. On the other hand, when a news anchor refers to a plane, they will often use "Maschine" rather than "Flugzeug". For planes, "Maschine" appears to be the slightly more "formal" term.

Comment: From my personal experience "maschine" is the less formal term, in both cases. I live in Austria (Lower Austria) though, so this might be a regional difference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Regierungsmitglieder kommen selten mit dem Motorrad, daher hörst Du es selten vom Nachrichtensprecher, der sonst auch, um sich hip zu geben, Jargon verwenden würde. Journalistenjargon wiederum ist kein guter Indikator für das, was die Leute auf der Straße sagen (Nichtpiloten, Nichtmotorradfahrer).

Comment: @userunknown: Sicher, aber auch bei Berichten über Verkehrsunfälle kann ich mir nur schwer den Gebrauch des Worts "Maschine" eines Motorrads vorstellen. Ein Bericht über einen Zwischenfall mit einer "Maschine" im Sinn eines Flugzeugs erscheint mir andererseits völlig idiomatisch.

Comment: @userunknown: Bezüglich des Journalistenjargons stimme ich dir völlig zu - ich sehe den Gebrauch von "Maschine" für "Flugzeug" noch als Grenzfall, da das Wort "Maschine" auch umgangssprachlich gebraucht werden kann, aber tendenziell als förmlichere Variante in journalistischen Texten verwendet zu werden scheint. In Österreich mag dies, wie von Nanogamer7 angedeutet, völlig anders sein.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a significant difference.

- "Maschine" refers to any kind of machine including airplanes, typically liners
- "Flugzeug" refers to an airplane of any kind including military ones
- "Flugmaschine" typically refers only to small planes (with few to no passengers) including historic ones

Most "Flugzeuge" can be called "Maschine" but most "Maschinen" are not a "Flugzeug".

Comment: Soll mit Punkt 2 gesagt werden, dass "Maschine" nicht für Militärmasch- ... - sorry - für Militärflugzeuge benutzt wird? Was ist eigentlich mit Segelflugzeugen?

Comment: @userunknown Mit Punkt 2 soll gesagt sein, dass "Flugzeug" für Militärmaschinen verwendet werden kann und es nicht unüblich ist. Punkt 1 sagt bereits, dass Maschine für jedes Flugzeug verwendet werden kann. Ich würde aber eher "Militärflugzeug" als "Militärmaschine" sagen und "Militärflugmaschiene" ist ungebräuchlich. Ich meine die meisten DInge durchaus so, wie ich sie schreibe.

Comment: Wie Du es schreibst ist aber missverständlich. Du sprichst von e. signifikanten Unterschied und kommst dann mit einer Liste aus 3 Punkten - da erwarte ich erstmal 3 Unterschiede. In a) sagst Du "typischerweise Linienflugzeuge", in b) "inklusive Militärflugzeuge". Ist das im Kontrast zu Punkt 1 zu lesen, ist das eine zweite Differenz - das ist unklar. Was ist mit Segelflugzeugen? Was ist mit den Unkrautvernichtungsflugzeugen? Was mit Hubschraubern?